# For flutter best way for custom space between two text

Tags: flutter, text

I am confuse about which is the best and right way for horizontal spacing between two text. I know `\t`, white space or some decoration can use for spacing. But I want to know exactly which is suitable way, because I want to rule standard rule and for large project. Please let me know.

I show example code that I use in my project and I used it usual but I think it is boring and not standard.

```
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0),
              child: Text(
                'Current Version\t\t\t:\t\t\t\t\t\t$appVersion',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

[image: Image for space between Current version text and version number]

As shown is figure, should I use `\t` or type manually space from keyboard that I want or two widget.

Comment: Have you tried Text.rich or Row with Expanded?

Comment: My code already fine and work before. I only want to know standard way. Yeah... the way you said is ```RichText``` is more nicer than the ```\t``` and keyboard space. Thank you. If anyone know any other best way please let me know.

Comment: yep it's standard way to do this please mark comment useful if you find this useful

Comment: yes. This is useful way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the UI using  [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)

```dart
RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
  children: [
    TextSpan(text: "Current Version"),
    WidgetSpan(
        child: SizedBox(
      width: 20, // your of space
    )),
    TextSpan(text: ":"),
    WidgetSpan(
        child: SizedBox(
      width: 20, // your of space
    )),
    TextSpan(text: appVersion),
  ],
)),
```